# Difference between list += ‘string’ and list +=[‘string’]

Tags: python, list, append

I have a question about the difference between list += ‘string’ and list +=[‘string’]. I mistook input a command in Python as:

```
Completedlist = []
Completedlist += ‘bob’
```

Which will return:

```
['b', 'o', 'b']
```

I am not quite sure about why this happens.
Besides, is there any difference between += and append in this scenario? I mean between completedlist.append(‘bob’) and completedlist += [‘bob’].
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `[].append('string')` and `[].append(['string'])` ?

Comment: First one is equivalent to `[] + list('string')`, second one is equivalent to `[] + ['string']`)

Comment: Thank you for your help, @DeepSpace. The list('string') will return ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'], however, x = [] x.append('string') x returns ['string'].

Answer (score 2):

The reason is documented, [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

`+=` just behaves like `.extend()` for a list, which appends contents of a list to the list. So, if you `+= string` then it takes the string like list and append each characters, but in the other case it adds the content of the list, which is the string I mean `bob` itself

Comment: How about my second question. The difference between .append and += for ['string']. Thanks.

Comment: Just like the same

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = list('dog')
>>> a += 'food'
>>> a
['d', 'o', 'g', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'd']

>>> a = list('dog')
>>> a += ['food']
>>> a
['d', 'o', 'g', 'food']
```

`+= ['food']` treats the whole string 'food' as a single list as a single element to be added to the list

`+= 'food'` treats the string 'food' as a **list of characters** to be added as elements to the list one-by-one

What might be a bit confusing here is that there are no separate data types for strings and characters in Python. A string is a list of 1-letter strings essentially.

Comment: How about my second question. The difference between .append and += for ['string']. Thanks.

Comment: `.append('string')` is the same as `+= ['string']`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have a further question. Why the list('string') will return ['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g'], however, x = [] x.append('string') x returns ['string']? This question raised from the comment below the question.

Comment: Because `list('string')` views 'string' as a sequence of characters, rather than a single element, just like in case 2 in my answer

Comment: Then should I use list(['string'])? Does [] create a list and list command is duplicated here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use it for what?