# random.choice appears to sometimes return keys that are not there

Tags: python

The following code

```py
import random

cards = {'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10}

def random_cards(n):
    dealt_cards = []
    for i in range(n):
        dealt_cards += random.choice(list(cards.keys()))
    print(dealt_cards)
```

produces this result

```
>>> random_cards(4)
['A', '4', '1', '0', '3']
>>>
```

The `1` isn't present in `cards.keys()`, and it doesn't come from the value of the `A` key.  I tested this with setting the value to 100 and it still placed the `1`.

Is `random.choice` broken?
If not, what is broken in my program?

Comment: paste your code as text

Comment: What do you think `dealt_cards += '10'` does?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Difference between list += ‘string’ and list +=\[‘string’\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64846845/3890632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stems from the fact that, to add to a `list`, you don't use `+=`, but `append`. The correct code is:

```py
def random_cards(n):
    dealt_cards = []
    for _ in range(n):
        dealt_cards.append(random.choice(list(cards.keys())))
    print(dealt_cards)
```

This is because addition with lists is defined only with iterables, which are converted to a list, then the two lists are concatenated. That is, `['c'] + 'ab' == ['c'] + list('ab') == ['c'] + ['a', 'b'] == ['c', 'a', 'b']`.